# When using fine-grained access in Github, how to give permission to packages of specific repo

Tags: github

When using fine-grained access in Github, how to give permission to packages (docker package in my case) of specific repo?

[image: Repo permission]

[image: Account permission]

- Its not documented at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens?apiVersion=2022-11-28
- Giving Read access to repo is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible atm with GitHub fine-grained access tokens.
The current documentation specifically mentions using classic tokens:

https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries